# python code in bookdown Rmarkdown does not run

Tags: python, r-markdown, bookdown, reticulate

I am trying to run some python code in rmarkdown using bookdown by copying this github repo - https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo. Everything looks ok when I knit the book either in HTML or PDF. The problem is when I try to run some python code in rmarkdown they do not run fully in console. Basically, the python codes that are in multiple line have the issue. Below are the codes for which I faced the issue -

The code

```
new_col = (iris_df.columns
            .str.replace('\(.*\)','')
            .str.strip()
            .str.upper()
            .str.replace(' ','_')
            )
```

and

```
sns.scatterplot(
  data = iris_df, 
  x = 'SEPAL_LENGTH', 
  y = 'SEPAL_WIDTH', 
  hue = 'TARGET', 
  palette = 'Set2')
```

do not run in console, the console look like this -

```
>>> new_col = (iris_df.columns
... 
...
```

and

```
>>> sns.scatterplot(
... 
...
```

Here is my all codes that I tried -

```
library(reticulate)
Sys.setenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON" = "C:\\Users\\mshar\\Anaconda3_2/python.exe")
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn

# To ignore warnings 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# Setting the Style for Visualization
plt.rc("font", size=15) # Runtime Configuration (rc)
sns.set(style="white") # white background style for seaborn plots
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
```

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris.keys()

iris_df = pd.DataFrame (data = iris.data, columns = iris.feature_names)
iris_df['target'] = iris.target
```

```
iris_df.sample(frac = 0.05)
iris_df.shape
(print(
  'The total number of rows and columns in the dataset is {} and {} respectively.'
  .format(iris_df.shape[0],iris_df.shape[1])))
iris_df.info()
```

```
new_col = (iris_df.columns
            .str.replace('\(.*\)','')
            .str.strip()
            .str.upper()
            .str.replace(' ','_')
            )
new_col
iris_df.columns = new_col
iris_df.info()
```

```
sns.scatterplot(
  data = iris_df, 
  x = 'SEPAL_LENGTH', 
  y = 'SEPAL_WIDTH', 
  hue = 'TARGET', 
  palette = 'Set2')
plt.xlabel('Sepal Length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal Width')
plt.title('Scatterplot of Sepal Length and Width for the Target Variable')
plt.show()
```

One last problem - When I run the `plot.show ()` code, it does not produce plot in Rmarkdown. But, when I knit the book, the plot is visible. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks